# What is the correct way to send a JSON string between javascript and PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am trying to send a tiny bit of data from javascript using XMLHttpRequest and a Json string to a PHP script to process it and return some response in the form of a Json string again, but I've ran into tons of issues and different methods that just won't work together properly, here's what has worked so far:

**Client**

```
json_string = '{"foo":"1","bar":"2"}';

var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
r.open('post', 'script.php', true);
r.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json; charset=utf-8');
r.setRequestHeader('Content-length', json_string.length);
r.setRequestHeader('Connection', 'close');
r.onload = function () {
    console.log(this.responseText);
};
r.send(json_string);
```

**Server**

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');

echo $json;
```

It can't get simpler than this, however I'm getting this warning:

> [09-Jan-2015 15:50:03 America/Mexico_City] PHP Deprecated:  Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line 0
>
> [09-Jan-2015 15:50:03 America/Mexico_City] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in Unknown on line 0

And of course the response text looks like this:

> **Deprecated**:  Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in **Unknown** on line **0**
>   
>   **Warning**:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in **Unknown** on line **0**
>   {"foo":"1","bar":"2"}"

What am I doing wrong? Why does PHP complain about already sent headers?

I'm using PHP 5.6.

Comment: I'd suggest you start using jquery to do ajax. I've already forgotten how to do it the manual way, and I'm glad I did.

Comment: plus one to developerwjk, and if you insist on doing it that way, just follow what ever the response said :D, open php.ini and set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to -1

Comment: The error you're getting, however, is because of `$json = file_get_contents('php://input');` You can't use `php://input` anymore.  You have to put your json in a request parameter and read that parameter with `$_POST`.

Comment: @Madbreaks - you can't send objects, only strings

Comment: @developerwjk So much misinformation and weak advice. There are a million and one reasons why someone might want to use native JS. `You can't use php://input anymore` - explain what *that* means. I used it today.\

Comment: @developerwjk can you provide the simplest example of how to put the json as a request parameter?

Comment: @developerwjk: `php://input` is the *correct* method to use.

Comment: @Madbreaks, The error message right there tells you that you can't do it without editing your php.ini to allow it, doesn't it? And yes, you might want to do ajax the manual way, if you're writing a library to compete with jquery, but that's about the only reason to do it.

Comment: Why don't use jQuery.ajax http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax ?

Comment: @developerwjk: `To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead.`  I think you just misread the error message.  `Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.`

Comment: @developerwjk Is there some reason you can't edit php.ini? Your statement that you'd only use native JS if you're developing a library to compete with jQuery is just silly. Your professional career has either been very short, or very narrow in focus.

Comment: @developerwjk - isn't it the other way around, [$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php)

Comment: Ok, maybe I read the docs wrong on $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA a while back. So `php://input` is the alternative to it, not part of it.  Ok, fine.

Comment: @developerwjk: I can see why you got confused.  `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` is not being used by the OP in his code, but instead *internally* by PHP.  PHP was updated and the php.ini was not updated to match the new version.

Comment: Although I agree that the simplest way would be to just edit php.ini, I may say that there'd be cases where I just wouldn't be bale to do so, just like in my current hosting service, so I'd be interested in how to send data using POST.

Comment: @arielnmz: In that case, you'd need to ask your hosting provider to update the php.ini file.  PHP is set up *incorrectly* and it should be their job to fix it!  If they don't fix it, I'd suggest finding another hosting service.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to edit your php.ini file and set `always_populate_raw_post_data = -1`.

Your code is working just fine.  `$json = file_get_contents('php://input');` is correct.

You are just getting a warning because your PHP was updated and you need to update the php.ini file for that new version.

More info here: https://www.bram.us/2014/10/26/php-5-6-automatically-populating-http_raw_post_data-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-a-future-version/

Comment: Okay, so I understand that the warning is because the default behavior was to automatically populate the data, and now in 5.6 it's necessary to explicitly indicate that PHP should _always populate raw data_ and what's deprecated is automatically assuming you want to _always populate raw data_, am I right?

Comment: @arielnmz: The default prior to PHP 5.6 was to populate the raw data when it got a MIME type it did not recognize via POST.  In PHP 5.6+, populating raw data is deprecated.  It should never be done.  Setting the ini value to -1 tells PHP to *never* to do so.  The ini values are 1: always, 0: only when MIME is not recognized, -1: never.

Comment: So the warning comes up because I don't have such setting set, right?

Comment: @arielnmz: Correct.  The default was to set `always_populate_raw_post_data = 0`.  PHP 5.6 wants it to be set to `-1`, so it throws a warning about that.

Comment: Ok, so, summing things up: the warning is because setting `always_populate_raw_post_data` to `0` (or don't explicitly setting it) is deprecated, but receiving input via `php://input` is still valid, right?

Comment: @arielnmz: Correct.  `php://input` is the correct way to do it.  The warning comes from the value of `always_populate_raw_post_data` not being set to `-1`.  For some reason the default value of `always_populate_raw_post_data` in PHP 5.6 is `0`!  It needs to be explicitly set to `-1`.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at some of my old code that does do Ajax without Jquery.  To send Json in a POST parameter is not that different from what you're doing already.

You really only need to change the headers you are setting, and give it a parameter name:

```
json_string = '{"foo":"1","bar":"2"}';

var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
r.open('post', 'script.php', true);
r.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
r.onload = function () {
    console.log(this.responseText);
};
r.send('json='+encodeURIComponent(json_string));
```

And then, of course in PHP:

```
$_POST['json']
```

Edit: Added `encodeURIComponent()`.